# Why can't I log the error message returned by Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to get error handling working in express, in my client app I have the following (React):

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/lists')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => setTitle(json.message))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
});
```

If the request succeeds I can log the message with no issue. However if an error is caught I just see `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` as the message. Trying to log `error.message` instead or `error` makes no difference. Express code is as follows (this is an example of an error thrown in the official docs):

```
app.get('/lists', (req, res) => {
  throw new Error('BROKEN');
});
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I access the message in the error?

Answer (score 0):

In the application controller, you need to pass the control to error handling middleware via `next` call.

Controller.js: Adding `next` to the API and passing the control to `next` middleware which should be error handler

```
app.get('/lists', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        throw {status: 500, message: 'server error'};
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do I need the catch and try? doesn't throw auto pass control to the middleware?

Comment: It does. try/catch only if you need to do any cleanup options like DB close, etc.

Answer (score 0):

add one check in first then:

```
useEffect( () => {
    fetch('/lists')
    .then( res => {
      if( res ) {
        return res.json()
      } else {    
        throw res
      }
    })
    .then( json => setTitle(json.message) )
    .catch( error => console.log(error) )
});
```